# Create readable string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column dataframe:

```
col1
1
2
3
4
```

I need to create another column where it will be a string like:

```
Result:
col1    col2
1       Value is 1
2       Value is 2
3       Value is 3
4       Value is 4
```

I know about formatted strings but not sure how to implement it in dataframe

Comment: `df['col2'] = 'Value is '+df['col1'].astype(str)`

Comment: `df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: "Value is " + str(row.col1), axis = 1)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to string and prepend values:

```
df['col2'] = 'Value is ' + df['col1'].astype(str)
```

Or use `f-string`s with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: f'Value is {x}')
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1        col2
0     1  Value is 1
1     2  Value is 2
2     3  Value is 3
3     4  Value is 4
```